# Grouping and sorting javascript array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

Given the following dummy data source:

```
// Dummy data source
var dbCustomerOrderItems = [];
dbCustomerOrderItems.push({ 
    Items: JSON.stringify([{ Sku: 'ABC1', Name: 'Name 1', Ordered: 1}])
});
dbCustomerOrderItems.push({ 
    Items: JSON.stringify([{ Sku: 'ABC2', Name: 'Name 2', Ordered: 3}])
});
dbCustomerOrderItems.push({ 
    Items: JSON.stringify([{ Sku: 'ABC2', Name: 'Name 2', Ordered: 1}])
});
```

I parse it into a linear array of objects like this:

```
// Init list
var popularProducts = [];

// Iterate throug customer orders
for (var i = 0; i < dbCustomerOrderItems.length; i++)
{
    // Parse items data
    try
    {
        var itemsData = JSON.parse(dbCustomerOrderItems[i].Items);
        for (var j = 0; j < itemsData.length; j++)
        {
            popularProducts.push({
                Name: itemsData[j].Sku +' | '+ (typeof itemsData[j].Name !== 'undefined' ? itemsData[j].Name : 'Product name not available'),
                Quantity: parseInt(itemsData[j].Ordered)
            });
        }
        itemsData = null;
    }
    catch (e) { }
}

// Debug
console.log(popularProducts);
```

Which outputs the following:

[image]

What I would like to do with this array of objects is:

1) Group the array by `Name`, so the consolidated data looks like this:

```
var groupedPopularProducts = [
    { Name: 'ABC1 | Name 1', Quantity: 1 },
    { Name: 'ABC2 | Name 2', Quantity: 4 }
];
```

2) Then I would like to sort this `groupedPopularProducts` by `Quantity` descending. So the resulting array looks like this:

```
var sortedPopularProducts = [
    { Name: 'ABC2 | Name 2', Quantity: 4 },
    { Name: 'ABC1 | Name 1', Quantity: 1 }
];
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You should look into lodash as it can do this and more. https://lodash.com/docs look specifically at the Collection section. It should be able to greatly simplify you life.

Comment: Why are you stringifying objects only to then immediate parse them bacK?

Comment: @torazaburo because this is how the data is stored in my source, I am merely trying to mimic it for my test case.

Comment: There are lots and lots of questions here about grouping objects in an array based on a property. Go ahead and look for them. Many of them have answers using underscore and lodash because they offer convenient group-by functions. However, those functions typically return a list of the elements in the group; you want a sum of the value of some property of each element in the group. That's easily enough done with a quick map. Then you want to sort the array of objects by the `Quantity` property, but that has also been extensively covered here on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution with one iteration and a temporary object.

```js
var dbCustomerOrderItems = [{ Items: JSON.stringify([{ Sku: 'ABC1', Name: 'Name 1', Ordered: 1 }]) }, { Items: JSON.stringify([{ Sku: 'ABC2', Name: 'Name 2', Ordered: 3 }]) }, { Items: JSON.stringify([{ Sku: 'ABC2', Name: 'Name 2', Ordered: 1 }]) }],
    result = dbCustomerOrderItems.reduce(function (r, a) {
        var o = JSON.parse(a.Items)[0],
            k = o.Sku + ' | ' + o.Name;
        if (!(k in r.obj)) {
            r.obj[k] = { Name: k, Quantity: 0 };
            r.array.push(r.obj[k]);
        }
        r.obj[k].Quantity += o.Ordered;
        return r;
    }, { array: [], obj: {} }).array.sort(function (a, b) { return b.Quantity - a.Quantity; });

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: Does this solution not assumes I have control over the data source? How can I make this work with the exact same data source as specified on the question? For me, the object's field `Items` is a json string. Nonetheless, good solution - I like it.

Comment: i am not sure, with your data structure. it looks a bit over engineered... do you mean i should take the first gray source box as input?

Comment: Yes, that's the data I have available to work with.

Comment: now it's working with the original data set.

Comment: Thanks, this works great. Nicely done.

Answer (score 1):

Group your elements into an dictionary like object and sort it as an array with an custom compare function.

```
var groupedProducts = {};

// grouping
for(var i=0;i<popularProducts.length;i++) {
    if (!(popularProducts[i].Name in groupedProducts)) {
        groupedProducts[popularProducts[i].Name] = popularProducts[i];
    }
    else {
        groupedProducts[popularProducts[i].Name].Quantity += popularProducts[i].Quantity;
    }
}

// sorting
var groupedProductsList = Object.keys(groupedProducts).map(function (key) {return groupedProducts[key]});

groupedProductsList.sort(function (a,b) {
    return b.Quantity - a.Quantity;
})


// Debug
console.log(groupedProductsList);
```

**Output:**

```
[ { Name: 'ABC2 | Name 2', Quantity: 4 },
 { Name: 'ABC1 | Name 1', Quantity: 1 } ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```js
var data = [
    { Name: 'ABC1 | Name 1', Quantity: 1 },
    { Name: 'ABC2 | Name 2', Quantity: 3 },
    { Name: 'ABC2 | Name 2', Quantity: 1 }];

var obj = {};
var result = [];
var _temp = [];

data.forEach(function(item){
  if(!obj[item.Name])
    obj[item.Name] = {
      Name:item.Name,
      Quantity:0
    };
  
  obj[item.Name].Quantity += item.Quantity;
});

for(var key in obj){
  _temp.push(obj[key]);
}

result = _temp.sort(function(a,b){
  return b.Quantity - a.Quantity
});

console.log(result)
```